# Producing a sensible, human-readable tree representation with scikit-learn DecisionTreeClassifier for categorical features?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree

This is a project using `scikit-learn` to build a decision tree that will also be rendered readable for the user.

The features are strings representing **discrete categories**. Some features are very sparse, consisting of a very large number of categories, with only a few instances in each.

`scikit-learn` seems to have only one class that can produce decision trees: `DecisionTreeClassifier`. This class only takes *numerical* data, so I had to process the `DataFrame` via `sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder`.

The tree was produced, but upon rendering, it made no sense. The various branches were controlled by decisions such as `Brand <= 7.5` We do expect the brand (a discrete category) to affect classification, but bunching up the (arbitrarily!) lower 7 brands together is guaranteed to be meaningless. Also, it's not human readable.

Is there a way to build a decision tree for categorical data with `scikit-learn` that will be meaningful and also human readable?

Comment: Use `LabelBinarizer` in place of `LabelEncoder`.

Comment: @user1808924 Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, I get a `MemoryError`, despite having 32GB RAM on my workstation. Guess I have too many categories.

Comment: You can order the `LabelBinarizer` transformer to produce sparse output vectors by specifying `sparse_output = True`.